# PrivateRoute reload page isAuthenticated first false in react.js

Tags: reactjs, redux

After login as a user

I enter the private path into the address bar, it returns isAuthenticated false for it, so I get redirected to the main page.

**PrivateRoute.js**

```
const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, isAuthenticated, ...rest}) => {
    return (
        <Route {...rest} render={props => (
            isAuthenticated ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/login"/>
        )}/>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {PrivateRoute})(PrivateRoute);
```

**PublicRoute.js**

```
const PublicRoute = ({component: Component, isAuthenticated, restricted, ...rest}) => {
    return (
        <Route {...rest} render={props => (
            isAuthenticated && restricted ? <Redirect to="/browser"/> : <Component {...props} />
        )}/>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {PublicRoute})(PublicRoute);
```

**App.js**

```
const App = () => (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
            <Layout>
                <Switch>
                    <PublicRoute restricted={true} exact path='/signup' component={Signup}/>
                    <PublicRoute restricted={true} exact path='/login' component={Login}/>

                    <PrivateRoute exact path='/browser' component={Browser}/>
                    <PrivateRoute path='/see-all' component={SeeAll}/>

                    <PublicRoute restricted={false} exact path='/' component={HomeView}/>
                </Switch>
            </Layout>
        </Router>
    </Provider>
);
export default App;
```

**Inspect result**

```
|      Result              |      File       |
----------------------------------------------
| isAuthenticate           | PrivateRoute.js |
| false                    | PrivateRoute.js |
| request_refresh          | auth.js         |
| {data: {…}, status: 200} | auth.js         |
| check_Authenticated      | auth.js         |
| {data: {…}, status: 200} | auth.js         |
| isAuthenticated          | PrivateRoute.js |
| true                     | PrivateRoute.js |
| load_user                | auth.js         |
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: check your state.auth.isAuthenticated before authenticating . is it true or false .